# I wish to insert into Table1, some data and some constants from table 2

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-insert

Below is the code I am using. sellingprice, type, BandID and IsPercent are constants
I am expecting multiple rows inserted as there are multiple products with Description XYZ

```
    Insert into Table1 ([itemid],[SellingPrice],[Type],[BandID],[IsPercent]) 
    values
    ((select ID from Table2 where Description like '%XYZ%'),26.5,0,20,1);
```

But I get error 'Subquery returned more than 1 value'
How do insert multiple values form one table, but not all, using the constants for the other column values?

Comment: The syntax is `INSERT .. SELECT` not `VALUES`. VALUES specifies specific values

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `VALUES` is a perfectively acceptable format, and has been supported since SQL Server 2008 (perhaps even 2005). See examples A and B of the [documnetation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-inserting-a-single-row-of-data).

Comment: @Larnu `VALUES` was always there, not just since 2005 but it was never supposed to contain query results. When I posted the comment the extra values were hidden out to the right. In any case, to get this query to work `INSERT SELECT` is needed. If the subquery returned a single value only, `VALUES` could be used but that's really ... unusual

Comment: The problem is that your comment comes across as if to say `VALUES` isn't valid syntax at all, @PanagiotisKanavos ; which simply isn't true. `INSERT...VALUES` *is* valid syntax, it's just isn't the syntax the OP should be using.

Comment: Appears to be a very similar question to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60177745/insert-multiple-rows-into-an-sql-table-using-a-select-statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way

```sql
Insert into Table1 ([itemid],[SellingPrice],[Type],[BandID],[IsPercent]) 
select ID as itemid, 26.5 as SellingPrice,0 as Type,20 as BandID,1 as IsPercent 
from Table2 
where Description like '%XYZ%';
```

Comment: Bingo. Thank for the help. That saves a lot of manual input